# Simplest implementation of ClosestIndexOf

Tags: c#, optimization, conditional-statements

I would like to write a C# string extension method `ClosestIndexOf(char, index)` that would get me the closest index of some character in a string around provided index.

Let's check some examples with my input string:

```
0         1         2         3         4         5    
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345
--------------------------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Input string length is 56 (I've added index positions that start with 0.

Example result calls:

```
input.ClosestIndexOf(' ', 30); // 27
input.ClosestIndexOf(' ', 35); // 39
input.ClosestIndexOf(' ', 50); // 50
input.ClosestIndexOf(' ', 19); // 17 & 21 have same offset, return 21
input.ClosestIndexOf(' ', 60); // OutOfRangeException
input.ClosestIndexOf('x', 30); // -1
```

I've written this so far, but it needs several more tests and is also ugly and with too many conditions.

```
// index is out of range
if (index > value.Length)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

// get closest index below and above specified "index" position
int below = result.LastIndexOf('-', index - 1);
int above = result.IndexOf('-', index);

// followed by conditions
```

I expect this problem to be more or less a math problem/expression so that I could avoid conditions and make it simpler.

[This is initial code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kNyui5) for you to work on. As you can see from the results my initial code works when specific character is found **below and above** or neither. but I would have to introduce additional conditions in cases when each of them has value -1. I haven't added those, because that's exactly what I'm trying to optimize.

What optimisations would you do on initial code to make it shorter, better performing and having less conditions?

Comment: @Robert: I'm not sure of the `index >= value.Length`... I think it should be `index > value.Length`. `"X".IndexOf('X', 1)` is -1 (while `LastIndexOf` throws). If you change it, then you can remove the `if (...)`, and then move the `IndexOf` first

Comment: And as a sidenote, I wouldn't do the code in that way. As written, if you have "0123456789" and you do the Closest starting from the index 8 of the char 9, the string `01234567` will be checked, while you could stop after two steps (aaah... I don't know how to explain)

Comment: @xanatos: You're correct. My actual code example on DotNetFiddle uses the greather than comparison. Let me edit the same on my question. And yes, you're right **I don't know what you mean in your second comment**.

Answer (score 0):

Get all occurences of your search character and the `found_index` of this occurence.

Calculate distance between your `search_index` and `found_index`.

```
  d = abs(s - f);
```

Keep occurence with smallest distance.

Comment: That's not really optimized is it? Suppose you have a very long string. Enumerating all matches would waste resources while searching just for closest above and below some index which would always use the same amount of resources regarless of string length.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not *the* best way to do it, but this should avoid most unnecessary checks.

```
public static int ClosestIndexOf(this string input, char c, int index)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    }
    if (index < 0 || index >= input.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
    }

    var lowerInRange = true;
    var higherInRange = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (lowerInRange)
        {
            var lower = index - i;
            lowerInRange = lower >= 0;
            if (lowerInRange && input[lower] == c)
            {
                return lower;
            }
        }

        if (higherInRange)
        {
            var higher = index + i;
            higherInRange = higher < input.Length;
            if (higherInRange && input[higher] == c)
            {
                return higher;
            }
        }

        if (!lowerInRange && !higherInRange)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: That's quite clever to iterate from index and returning immediately when one of them is matched. Although your method always returns the lower index when higher and lower both have a match at the same offset from index. I'm doing the opposite, but that could be easily done by switching order of your `lowerInRange` and `higherInRange` is statements.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to understand, efficient & be correct :')

```
public static int ClosestIndexOf(this string input, char c, int startIndex)
{
    var inputLength = input.Length;
    if (inputLength == 0)
        return -1;

    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex >= inputLength)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex");

    int leftIndex = startIndex;
    int rightIndex = startIndex;

    bool canCheckLeftIndex = true;
    bool canCheckRightIndex = true;

    do
    {
        if (canCheckLeftIndex && input[leftIndex] == c) return leftIndex;
        if (canCheckRightIndex && input[rightIndex] == c) return rightIndex;

        leftIndex--;
        rightIndex++;

        canCheckLeftIndex = leftIndex >= 0;
        canCheckRightIndex = rightIndex < inputLength;
    } while (canCheckLeftIndex || canCheckRightIndex);

    return -1;
}
```

Your initial code: don't do any mathematic tricks / try to be clever, I would not want to see that code in production. It's hard to see that your code is correct.

Comment: Math.Max could easily be replaced by an inline if statement: `result = above < 0 ? below : above`

Comment: Your code is actually a shortened version of @Corak's code where he uses verbose `if` codeblocks compared to yours and doing a `for` loop where `do-while` is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I've eliminated as many conditions as possible while keeping the whole code maintainable and easily readable which is also one of the main objectives because maintaining unreadable code is just as bad as developing it all from scratch.

```
public static int ClosestIndexOf(this string input, string value, int startIndex)
{
    // get closest index below and above specified "startIndex" position
    int above = input.IndexOf(value, startIndex);
    int below = input.LastIndexOf(value, startIndex);

    int middle = (below + above) / 2;

    int result;
    if (middle > startIndex)
        result = below == -1 ? above : below;
    else
        result = above == -1 ? below : above;

    return result;
}
```

I've removed the invalid `startIndex` check because `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` do that already. Everything else is pretty much readable and understandable.

Comment: There is no way this is easily readable for someone who has no experience with this problem before (`mid` huh?).  The code should convince me that it will work with reading only once. Just my friendly opinion. Take care.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa: I renamed `mid` to `middle` so there's no disambiguation. I'm using it purely to cleverly determine which index (`above` or `below`) is closer to `startIndex`. Is it actually tricky to understand? The good thing is also, that I can now get closest index of a string and not only a specific character. I can use this to determine closest paragraph end - searching for `</p>` in some HTML string that I'd like to shorten. Searching for a single character would make this quite a bit harder.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, current implementation is incorrect: `string test = "012345"; ClosestIndexOf(test, "5", 1); // returns -1, not 5`

Comment: @ASh: Thanks for this. That's actually a bug and I+ll have to resolve it.